# Clear memory when new ViewController is presented

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have some buttons in my app interface that act like this

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
let nextVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("customVC") as! customVC
self.presentViewController(nextVC, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

When user presses them - the new ViewController is shown and everything is ok except one thing - I think that previous ViewController is still in memory. How can i clear it?

Comment: Maybe next answer will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29113738/6124910 Good luck!

Comment: So i need to add self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil) in the beginning if this method?

Comment: how much memory previous vc consumes?  Since ios 5 manual memory management replaced with ARC. 

Check this https://www.raywenderlich.com/5677/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-part-1

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
  self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: {() -> Void in
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: { _ in })
```

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid jump in animations I use this code:

```
self.setViewControllers([New_View_Controller_Class()], animated: true)
```